# Can I extend PieChart in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

The idea is to have a class that extends PieChart, to use only it as abstract.

This class is in a separate project, for components used in another app.

I'm trying to do this:

```
class DiamondPieChart @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : PieChart(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    ...

}
```

To be able to use in another module only this in the layout:

```
<DiamondPieChart
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

Error return:

Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
DiamondPieChart, unresolved supertypes: com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart

Comment: SOLVED:

Just change "implementation" to "api" in import.
api "com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v${versions.mpandroidchart}"

Comment: Hi. Glad you sorted this out. Please answer your own question and accept it. This will help others and close this issue, which is solved now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: 
Just change "implementation" to "api" in import. api "**com**.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v${versions.mpandroidchart}"